# Comparison of Rademacher and Gaussian moments under linear transformations

Tags: pr.probability, gaussian, moments

Let $X$ be an $n$ dimensional standard Gaussian and let $U$ be an $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix. Then, the random vector $Z = U^\top X$ is also distributed as a standard Gaussian in $R^n$ and we have $E[\prod_{i=1}^n Z_i^2] = 1$ by independence.

Is there a method for bounding such functions if $X$ was an $n$ dimensional vector where each coordinate is an independent Rademacher $\pm1$ random variable. For instance, for $Z = U^\top X$, the coordinates are not independent anymore. Can one show that $E[\prod_{i=1}^n Z_i^2]$ is polynomial in $n$ or $\exp(n)$ even in this setting?

More generally, is there a way of comparing such quantities to the Gaussian setting or universality statements that are applicable in such settings where the random vector may have some weak dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the arithmetic mean--geometric mean inequality and the condition $Z=U^\top X$ for an orthogonal matrix $U$,
$$\prod_1^n Z_i^2\le\Big(\frac1n\sum_1^n Z_i^2\Big)^n
=\Big(\frac1n\sum_1^n X_i^2\Big)^n=1,$$
since $X_i=\pm1$ for all $i$. So,
$$E\prod_1^n Z_i^2\le1,$$
as desired.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't realize that this had a simple proof. I need to be able to bound expectation of other functions as well where it is easy to compute them in the Gaussian case, e.g. $E[\prod_{i=1}^n f(Z_i)]$ for some function $f$, so I was wondering if there is a general method for comparing to the Gaussian setting?

Comment: @brownianmotion : It would be better in every respect that I can think of if the question for general $f$ be posted separately. If you think that your posted question has been fully answered, can you please mark the answer accordingly?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have marked the questions as being answered and opened a new question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430795/comaprison-of-rademacher-and-gaussian-expected-values-under-linear-transformatio

Comment: @brownianmotion : That new question seems interesting but difficult. I would be (pleasantly) surprised if there is an answer to it within a few pages.